# c++ Indicator / Loading Wheel

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder, c++builder-xe4

I'm using RAD Studio 4 C++ builder and would like to display an Indicator wheel while my data sources was fetching data from the DB. I know FireMonkey has an Indicator wheel but c++ builder doesn't seem to have such a component.

Does anyone know of a component I could use ?

Comment: Do you think you have provided all the required information necessary to answer your question?  For example what platform are you targetting?

Comment: I believe I have, that's why I said I'm using RAD Studio 4 and specifically C++ Builder. This is a component question, specific to the development suite.

Comment: And what's RAD Studio 4 used to target?

Comment: Windows OS 7/8. With SQL Database in background. It's not for the mobile App development suite. That I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TAnimate` component is what you are looking for.  Find an .avi video that suits your needs, load it into `TAnimate`, and perform your DB work in a separate thread so `TAnimate` is not blocked from running.